# IndexOutOfRangeException when hosting ASP.NET MVC app on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, iis, production-environment

We have a ASP.NET MVC app that runs perfectly inside Visual Studio 2015 but when hosting it on IIS, we get an IndexOutOfRangeException. The stack trace doesn't point to our code though so unsure what the issue is. We have tried on multiple servers and got the same result.

.NET Framework Version 4.5

ASP.NET MVC Version 5.0.0

[image: Exception and stack trace]

Comment: You probably shouldn't have posted the full URL to that site (which by the way is working fine here).

Comment: you're right. and its working as we rolled back to an earlier backup. thanks. the question still stands though.

Comment: Also, screenshots are useful, but the text from them should always be included in the question.

Comment: [going from here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpApplication.cs,2396) I guess missing sections or attributes in machine.config or web.config (moduleconfigurationinfo).

Comment: @dlatikay That's a pretty good guess. Since the previous app works, machine.config must be fine. Probably worth trying the old web.config with the new site and see what happens with that.

Comment: @DavidG already done that. no luck with the old web.config

Comment: In that case there's not a lot we can do I suspect. Maybe try a brand new blank MVC app and see if that deploys fine.

Comment: @DavidG other apps do deploy fine

Comment: Assuming you use source control, can you deploy an older version of your code? If so, what has changed since then?

Comment: @DavidG That's the issue, we don't exactly know what version of code was deployed last.

Comment: Oh boy, then you desperately need to review your deployment procedures. You should be tagging your source control or branching off releases or whatever.

Comment: @DavidG we normally do all that, but we inherited this project from another vendor and not much we can do about it.

Comment: Then your are limited to going back a bunch of commits, trying that. If it works, roll forward a bit more, try that. etc. etc.

Comment: Another obvious question, but one that needs to be asked, new and old are pointing to the same resources?  Same database, same web services, etc?

Comment: @Duston yes, the configuration was kept intact